# How to add Gilroy fonts in react js application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, font-family

I want to add gilroy font to my react js project by importing

```
@import url('https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/gilroy-bold');
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Create a fonts folder in src
like this -

```
src/fonts
```

Download [Gilroy fonts](https://www.dafontfree.io/gilroy-font-family/) and add files in the fonts folder

Add the below code in index.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
  src: local('Gilroy-Bold'), url(./fonts/Gilroy-Bold.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium';
  src: local('Gilroy-Medium'), url(./fonts/Gilroy-Medium.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gilroy-Light';
  src: local('Gilroy-Light'), url(./fonts/Gilroy-Light.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Add below code in your code

```
.header_label {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #A29C9C;
    opacity: 1;
}
.subHeader_label {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #A29C9C;
    opacity: 1;
}
.text_label {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.75rem;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Light', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #A29C9C;
    opacity: 1;
}
```